# Azure Devops image in readme from relative path

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I'm trying to add an image to my readme but I can't get it to render.
As far as I can see online my current setup should work.

My folder structure is like so:

[image]

And then I tried to use the image located in the resources directory, but that did not work:

```
![Architecture view for AllProjects.png](./Resources/Architecture-view-for-AllProjects.png)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work well for me: Replace the space with `&#32;` or `%20`.

```
![Architecture view for AllProjects.png](./Resources/Architecture%20view%20for%20AllProjects.png)

![Architecture view for AllProjects.png](./Resources/Architecture&#32;view&#32;for&#32;AllProjects.png)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your file is `Architecture view for AllProjects.png` so if you add `-` all should be fine.

Please check out [here - Spaces in path to image file](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf/issues/54).

I tried encoding it with `%20` but link was still broken. So your only/best way is to add `-` to the name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look  over my question. the answer of Vito Lui worked, either `&#32;` or `%20` displayed the image correctly for me. I'd thought replacing spaces with `-` would do the trick since a couple lines above this image i have a link to a wiki document that includes spaces, and the relative link there works. Something like: `[my wiki link](/my-wiki-link)`.So it works for wiki page links, but not for images inside a git repo for some reason, but such are the mysteries of life.